# Editable gridview is not working

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I have an editable gridview which the user can edit each row just by pressing linkbutton. I am getting an error and it stops my work. please help me.

**HTML**

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvList" runat="server" class="gv" CellPadding="2"  
Font-Names="Calibri" ForeColor="#333333"
Font-Size="16px" Width="500px" AutoGenerateColumns="true" OnRowCancelingEdit="gvList_RowCancelingEdit"
OnRowEditing="gvList_RowEditing" OnRowUpdating="gvList_RowUpdating">
     <Columns>
         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="User Name" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White"  HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true" ItemStyle-Width="170px">
         <ItemTemplate>
              <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblUsername" Text='<%# Eval("cUserName") %>'></asp:Label>
         </ItemTemplate>
         <EditItemTemplate>
              <asp:TextBox ID="Editusername" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("cUserName") %>'></asp:TextBox>
         </EditItemTemplate>

         </asp:TemplateField>
         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Dept User" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White"  HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true" ItemStyle-Width="170px">
         <ItemTemplate>
              <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblDept" Text='<%#  iif(Eval("lDeptUser"),"Yes","No")  %>'></asp:Label>
         </ItemTemplate>
         <EditItemTemplate>
              <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server" >
              <asp:ListItem>Yes</asp:ListItem>
              <asp:ListItem>No</asp:ListItem>
              </asp:RadioButtonList>
          </EditItemTemplate>
          </asp:TemplateField>

          <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Actions" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true" ItemStyle-Width="160px">
          <ItemTemplate>
              <asp:LinkButton  ID="btnedit" CommandName="Edit" runat="server" Text="Edit" />
              <asp:LinkButton ID="btnDelete" CommandName="Delete" runat="server" Text="Delete" />
          </ItemTemplate>
          <EditItemTemplate>
               <asp:LinkButton ID="btnUpdate" CommandName="Update" runat="server" Text="Update" />
               <asp:LinkButton  ID="btnCancel" CommandName="Cancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" />
           </EditItemTemplate>
                    <HeaderStyle Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White"></HeaderStyle>
                    <ItemStyle Width="120px"></ItemStyle>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
                <EmptyDataTemplate>
                    No records available
                </EmptyDataTemplate>
                <HeaderStyle BackColor="#808380" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" VerticalAlign="Top" />
                <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
                <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#E3E3E3" />
            </asp:GridView>
```

**VB**

```
Protected Sub gvList_RowUpdating(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewUpdateEventArgs) Handles gvList.RowUpdating

    Dim oldname = DirectCast(gvList.Rows(e.RowIndex).FindControl("lblUsername"), Label)
    Dim username As String = DirectCast(gvList.Rows(e.RowIndex).FindControl("Editusername"), TextBox).Text
    Dim tempUser = DirectCast(gvList.Rows(e.RowIndex).FindControl("RadioButtonList1"), RadioButtonList).SelectedIndex
    Dim query As String = "Update Intranet.dbo.Gn_ISCoordinators SET cUserName=@uname" +
                          ",lDeptUser=@dept WHERE cUserName=@oldName"

    Using con = New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("IntranetConnectionString").ConnectionString)
        con.Open()
        Dim cmd = New SqlCommand(query, con)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uname", username)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dept", Convert.ToByte(tempUser))
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@oldname", oldname)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using

    gvList.EditIndex = -1
    GetList()
End Sub
```

The problem is on the `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` it gives me `The parameterized query '(@uname nvarchar(7),@dept tinyint,@oldname nvarchar(4000))Update' expects the parameter '@oldname', which was not supplied.`

Any thing wrong in my query?

Comment: After chaning ur typo mistak '@oldname' if u still get nothing then pls check have you use page.ispostback while binding gridview `if (!Page.IsPostBack) {gridviewBIND} ` refer http://satindersinght.blogspot.in/2012/08/how-to-addupdate-record-using-gridview.html

Comment: @Satindersingh yeah i did that before.

Comment: your code looks fine, but this line `command.commandtype = commandtype.text` is missing may be dat the problem

Comment: You will get this error if the variable (in this case `oldname`) is `Nothing`.

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
Dim oldname as Label =gvList.Rows(e.RowIndex).FindControl("lblUsername")
    Dim username as TextBox = gvList.Rows(e.RowIndex).FindControl("Editusername")
    Dim tempUser as RadioButtonList = DirectCast(gvList.Rows(e.RowIndex).FindControl("RadioButtonList1"), RadioButtonList).SelectedIndex  


   Dim query As String = "Update Intranet.dbo.Gn_ISCoordinators SET cUserName=@uname" +
                              ",lDeptUser=@dept WHERE cUserName=@oldname"
Using con = New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("IntranetConnectionString").ConnectionString)
        con.Open()
        Dim cmd = New SqlCommand(query, con)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uname", username.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dept", Convert.ToByte(tempUser.SelectedIndex))
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@oldname", oldname.Text)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
```

you have change the parameter name by making "N" capital in @oldName,so due to that

you are getting that Error

Comment: even after the change i'm having the same problem

Comment: are you getting data in username ,tempUser,oldname?

Comment: I am trying to get data, but when i do the debugging and check the value in the username, tempUserm and oldname, no data!

Comment: I am getting this error `Object reference not set to an instance of an object. ` on the `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@oldname", oldname.Text)`

Comment: first see you will get data in oldname or not,if you got than try this .save that value in another variable and than pass that variable to parametes .so it look like ,olnm=oldname.text than add this parameter to cmd like this cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@oldname", olnm)

Answer (score 2):

there is a typo in your parameter

```
  Dim query As String = "Update Intranet.dbo.Gn_ISCoordinators SET cUserName=@uname" +
                      ",lDeptUser=@dept WHERE cUserName=@oldName"
```

And you have

```
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@oldname", oldname)
```

isn't it should be

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@oldName", oldname)
```

there is capital and small letter mistake.

Comment: I am getting the same exactly problem!!

Comment: Is there a problem in getting the label, textbox, and rbl data using `DirectCast` ??

Comment: becuase when i do debugging, the value in all of these is nothing :S

Comment: You need to get the Text of the `Label` if the label exists.

Answer (score 2):

Try this
Code look fine, but this line `command.commandtype = commandtype.text` is missing may be that the problem.

Also while passing parameter Addwithvalue use `username.text` instead on `username` same for other controls too

```
Dim oldname As Label = DirectCast(gvList.Rows(e.RowIndex).FindControl("lblUsername"), Label)
Dim username As TextBox = DirectCast(gvList.Rows(e.RowIndex).FindControl("Editusername"), TextBox).Text
Dim tempUser As RadioButton = DirectCast(gvList.Rows(e.RowIndex).FindControl("RadioButtonList1"), RadioButtonList).SelectedIndex
Dim query As String = "Update Intranet.dbo.Gn_ISCoordinators SET cUserName=@uname, lDeptUser=@dept WHERE cUserName=@oldName"

Using con = New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("IntranetConnectionString").ConnectionString)
    con.Open()
    Dim cmd = New SqlCommand(query, con)
    cmd.commandtype = commandtype.text  
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uname", username.text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dept", Convert.ToByte(tempUser.selectedvalue))
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@oldname", oldname.text)
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Using

gvList.EditIndex = -1
GetList()
```

Answer (score 2):

Sorry I dont have enough rep to comment so I have to answer here...

Why are you casting label to label and trying to use it as string?:

```
Dim oldname as string = DirectCast(gvList.Rows(e.RowIndex).FindControl("lblUsername"), Label).text
```

seems more appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

Im not sure about this but maybe because when you tried to hit the edit button and the gridview's mode is in edit mode the lblUsername label will be changed to Editusername textbox.. So what I suggest is you try to put a global variable string that will store the data of the lblUsername before updating or editing..

Comment: Please let me know if you have tried the approach.. maybe you can store the value of the label on the gridview editing event and then get the variables value on updating..